# How to know ASCII / UTF code of emojis?

Tags: java, android, ascii, emoji, utf

I need to obtain the codes of the emojis entered on an `EditText` in an Android App.
I've tried this, but it **always returns me ASCII values 55356 and 55357** for all the emojis.

```
    end   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFinal);
    botom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    intro = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtIntro);

    botom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String t = intro.getText().toString();
            if (t != null && t != ""){
                char c = t.charAt(0);
                end.setText((int)c+"");
            }
        }
    });
```

Can I convert them to UTF? If so, how?
Or there is another enconding specific for emojis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about ASCII. If you only think you are using ASCII, you're almost certainly not.

`charAt` does not return ASCII values. It returns a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint.

It's unclear what you want to do with the emoji. It seems that you are splitting it out of the whole string and assuming it is the first text element in the string. Maybe that's just test code.

You can take UTF-16 code units until you have a whole character. That's one or two code units. The `Character` class has a method for that: [codePointAt(CharSequence seq, int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt-java.lang.CharSequence-int-). There are other methods that you could use to depending on what you are trying to accomplish. The class description is good reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the encoding by using `t.getBytes("UTF8")`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) is some more info on the `getBytes` method.

Comment: Seems to return ramdon caracters even if the emoji remains unchanged.

Comment: Is this when using `char c = t.getBytes("UTF8")[0]`?

Comment: When using that _end_ remains blank

Comment: What are the rest of the bytes?